# Store values to database without using form action

Tags: php, html, sql

I have several web pages created that captures information from user inputs and stores them into session variables in PHP tags inside the html. Finally I echo back the values from the session all on the same page and ask the user if all inputs are correct. I would like to include a submit button at the bottom of the page for the user to submit the session values into the database. I am not sure how to take the values from inside the current page in session variables and store to database. Here is an example of code I currently have.

```
   <?php
   session_start();
   $name = $_SESSION['name'];

   echo "<br>Is this name right?: ".$name;
   ?>
```

I have already created the database and respective columns. I am familiar with storing values in form submission, however I have always done this by embedding a file in the form action and obtaining the values using $_POST[''] to get values of inputs of current form.

Comment: Way is you not only use "$_SESSION['name']" for get the value and in the post from you has `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="savenow" />`that you can test for see if the use has request to save the values.

Comment: So basically you're reloading the page three times to submit a form ?

Comment: Its about 40 values that are collected over the course of 4 or 5 pages during account creation. It will be more complex, with the options to change values if mistakes. Is there a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in your queries, just substitute $_POST with $_SESSION. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Can I add insert my connection, query, etc from right here, or do I need to have it in an external page and use form action? If I can insert it right here, how do I trigger it?

Comment: Ahh, I think you're confused- forms are NOT required in order for database interactions to take place. There's no need for an external trigger; you can just make a DB query with the $_SESSION data :)

Comment: Ahh, you're right. I was confused. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: No probs- remember to accept as answer if it did indeed answer your question :)!